# Close as duplicate fails on HTTPS links

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, ssl

When closing a question as a duplicate there is a text box which says: "search, or enter a question link or numeric id". You can copy and paste a question link into here, but this fails if the URL starts with `https://` instead of `http://`, with the message "Your search returned no matches; please try a different search".

Comment: Well, considering that HTTPS isn't officially supported yet, that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @animuson I'm using HTTPS just fine. I didn't say it was surprising, just that it was a bug.

Comment: My browser is using HTTPS without my having done anything to enable it, so presumably HTTPS is now "officially supported", and this bug is still a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix rolling out in build rev `2014.2.14.1957` on meta and `2014.2.14.1372` on sites.

Answer (score 4):

Aha! Found the little bug, though the team will have to fix it.

Your question URL is this:

> **https**://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033298/python-logic-in-assignment

For some reason, if you change the `https` to `http` it works. Weird, but true. So it looks like all the team has to do is also recognize `https` URL's in the possible duplicate window thingy.

Comment: Ah, I see. Probably due to my HTTPS Everywhere extension in Chrome.

Comment: @SteinarLima Probably, but it's still a bug. (HTTPS Everywhere kind of breakes some SE things, so they may not fix it) However, it seems like it's not extention specific, all HTTPS URL's would be affected so I think it should be fixed.

Comment: Isn’t this just restating the bug (“fails if the URL starts with `https://` instead of `http://`”)?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yeah... another question got merged with it so it's kinda weird (this was from the other question, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216328/question-not-found-when-trying-to-mark-as-duplicate).

Comment: @hichris123 Ah, that explains it.