# Question not found when trying to mark as duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, ssl

I tried to mark [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152059/python-for-loop-with-or) question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033298/python-logic-in-assignment). However - when pasting the link to the question in the input field, I got a

> Your search returned no matches; please try a different search

error. It eventually found the question when I used the numerical id. Is this a bug?

Comment: Didn't realize I did that, @hichris123. About time, I guess - there'll probably be more of these. In fact, this one is [actually a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208784/close-as-duplicate-fails-on-https-links)