# https links to same site don't auto-prettify

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, ssl

Normally, when one posts a link to a question on the same site, it automatically 'prettyfies' the link.

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/https-links-to-same-site-dont-auto-prettify` becomes [https links to same site don't auto-prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/https-links-to-same-site-dont-auto-prettify)

However, if the link is an https link, this doesn't happen.

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/https-links-to-same-site-dont-auto-prettify` is just [https links to same site don't auto-prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/https-links-to-same-site-dont-auto-prettify)

As StackExchange is supporting/encouraging the use of https more and the general population seems to be more inclined to use https for every day browsing, it would be nice if one didn't need to fix the links in the questions and answers.

Comment: HTTPS still isn't officially supported, but worth keeping this around as a reminder.

Comment: This is in the same class as this problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208784/close-as-duplicate-fails-on-https-links with https duplicate links. I figure we'll find a few more edge cases with these now that they're being used more frequently.

Comment: reproduced, fix incoming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.2.14.1957` on meta and `2014.2.14.1372` on sites.

Comment: Nice! Will this work for protocol-relative links (e.g. `//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/218060`) too?

Comment: no, it won't work for protocol relative urls, I imagine it would make sense to rewrite question urls to be protocol relative once we go live with official support for https on all sites