# Questions don't link if the URL uses HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions, ssl

When linking a question via HTTPS, the question doesn't appear in the Linked Questions sidebar.

In the question [My avatar automatically changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226463/my-avatar-automatically-changed), this was the initial screenshot:

[image: Initial sidebar]

So then the question was edited to use HTTP in the link instead of HTTPS:
[image: Revision history]

After that, the question is now shown in the Linked Questions sidebar:
[image: Final Sidebar]

I've also repro'ed this in a comment on this post: [Meta is... Japanese?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217670/meta-is-japanese). So if you use HTTPS in the URL, it doesn't link the posts. However, if you use HTTP instead of HTTPS, it works. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: HTTPS isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: @AnnaLear True, however this isn't so much a problem with HTTPS everywhere or anything. I'm assuming the system just isn't detecting links with HTTPS to link them together.

Comment: Sure, but we don't support HTTPS Everywhere and I personally hesitate encouraging HTTPS links until we actually expect them to work 100% of the time.

Comment: Similar, but already fixed, issue: [https links to same site don't auto-prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218060/https-links-to-same-site-dont-auto-prettify)

Comment: Also, it would be really nice if this could be made to also work for protocol-relative links.

Comment: @Anna won't it be easy enough to strip the https in the linked sidebar and link only to the non secured version?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, stripping http/https from all SE links, making them protocol-relative, would be a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator sure, but I'm talking only on Linked questions in the sidebar as a temporary workaround, which hopefully is faster to implement. :)

Comment: @Deduplicator Not a good idea until we do support HTTPS across the board. It sort of usually works on main sites, but meta sites can't support it at all, so protocol-relative links from HTTPS main to meta are always broken. Having said that, protocol-relative links are on our list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure off the top of my head how Linked question list is built/maintained, but this doesn't look like a display bug.

Comment: looking into this, the links in the linked sidebar are already relative to the current page (like in `/q/{id}`)

Comment: protocol relative links are not picked up as links by the comment mini-markdown

Comment: @m0sa thanks for looking into this! Anyway, it's not protocol relative, if I now post `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248382/chat-link-in-top-bar-is-not-site-specific` which is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248382/chat-link-in-top-bar-is-not-site-specific it will not show as Linked. Probably the protocol is being removed somewhere in the code?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was saying that all the links in the Linked section are already relative (not in the actual comment/post though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Https links will be picked up as linked posts after build rev `2015.2.10.3062` on meta and `2015.2.10.2282` on sites roll out. They will be rendered as relative in the linked sidebar. In the actual post/comment they will still be rendered as they were entered by the author.

Protocol relative URLs are not rendered by the markdown engine as links, I see no need to add support for them in the linked post detection.

Comment: If you got a  minute, can you please elaborate on the "why" part [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280355/why-arent-protocol-relative-links-recognized-as-linked-questions)?

Comment: With regards to *"I see no need to add support for them in the linked post detection"* - What about in linked references i.e. `[1]://meta.SE...`